# Use VBA in excel to extract first and last delimited substring (non-empty substring)

Tags: vba, string, excel-formula, substring, csv

I have a column in which each cell contains data in this format:

```
ABC |  DEF |  GHI |   |

ABC |  DEF |  GHI | JKL |

ABC |  DEF |   |   |
```

I need to extract the first and last valid (i.e. not empty) sub-strings.
I can extract the first/last substring easily enough using a formula (though it's clunky):

```
 FIRST SUBSTRING
        =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(4-4)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))

LAST SUBSTRING
        =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),(4-1)*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

This basically uses SUBSTITUE to replace the "|" delim with spaces, then uses MID to the extract the nth substring followed by TRIM to replace the extra spaces... but if the last delimited substring is empty it returns an empty string (as its meant to i guess).

How can I modify this formula to extract the last valid substring (i.e. not empty " "). Could someone please show me how to do this using VBA code ?

```
    ABC |  DEF |  GHI |   |
Output column 1: ABC
Output column 2: GHI

    ABC |  DEF |  GHI | JKL |
Output column 1: ABC
Output column 2: JKL

    ABC |  DEF |   |   |
Output column 1: ABC
Output column 2: DEF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say your worksheet is WS
and your values starts at cell A2 till A120

```
dim zeValue$, out1$, out2$
dim i as int

for i = 2 to 120
   zeValue = replace(replace(WS.range("A" & i),' ',''),'|','')
   out1 = left$(zeValue,3)
   out2 = right$(WS.range(zeValue, 3)
   debug.print('out1 : '+out1)
   debug.print('out2 : '+out2)
next i
```

Not tested but that should work
Good luck pal !